# Does ver only support toolbox?

Tags: matlab

The link [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-help-summary-contents-m.html) mentions that the following line is placed in the second line of the `Contents.m` file, calling `ver` will print it out as the version.

```
  % Version 1.0.0.0 20-Dec-2016
```

Does this work only for toolboxes? I have a non-toolbox folder `foo`. If I do `ver foo`, it said it cannot find the correct format of version.

Comment: I think that'll be because your self-created non-toolbox folder will not have an info file where a version flag is set. I can however not find such a file in a toolbox folder.

Comment: @Adriaan: the help page of ver says ' ver product displays, in addition to the header information:

    The current version number for product, where product is the name of the folder that contains the Contents.m file for the product you are inquiring about. ' That is why I looked into Contents.m.

Comment: Ah, I just checked various `Contents.m` files, they only give the name of the toolbox, TMW trademark and in some cases a few functions contain within the toolbox. I can't find anything about a version number in that specific file.

Answer (score 1):

It works for any folder on the MATLAB path.

Create a folder called `mytmpfolder`, and put in it the following file `Contents.m`:

**Contents.m**

```
% MYTMPFOLDER
% Version 2.1.8 (My Version Name) 16-Dec-2016
%
% Description goes here.
%
% MYTMPFOLDER
% mytmpfolder - Some code for doing stuff.
```

Make sure `mytmpfolder` is on the MATLAB path. Then type:

```
>> help mytmpfolder
  mytmpfolder
  Version 2.1.8 (My Version Name) 16-Dec-2016

  Description goes here.

  mytmpfolder
  mytmpfolder - Some code for doing stuff.

>> ver mytmpfolder
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
MATLAB License Number: 628350
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise  Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYTMPFOLDER                                           Version 2.1.8       (My Version Name)

>> v = ver('mytmpfolder')
v = 
       Name: 'MYTMPFOLDER'
    Version: '2.1.8'
    Release: '(My Version Name)'
       Date: '16-Dec-2016'
```

By the way, there's not really any such thing as a "toolbox folder" vs a "non-toolbox folder". Toolboxes are products from MathWorks, or products that other people make, but once they're installed they're really just folders full of code like any other folders full of code. You'd usually use a mechanism like `Contents.m` to indicate that a folder represented a sort of special point that collected together an important set of code, but it's up to you.

Comment: I use 2016. And the following is what I have. >> help mytmpfolder
  mytmpfolder
  Version 2.1.8 (My Version Name) 16-Dec-2016
 
  Description goes here.
 
  mytmpfolder
  mytmpfolder - Some code for doing stuff.

Comment: >> ver mytmpfolder
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
MATLAB License Number: 544094
Operating System: Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 3 13:32:45 EST 2014 x86_64
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: No properly formatted Contents.m file was found for 'mytmpfolder'. 
> In ver (line 54)